# how could i config the gitlab CI/CD，it always failed “ exit status 255”

Tags: gitlab, cicd

i have config the gitlab-runner for my project in Windows.

and i also using a sample GitLab CI/CD configuration file which supply by gitlab,

but everytime CI/CD working there is always show me a error like below：

"error: could not lock config file D:\gitlab_runner\builds\XJWuKoWT\0\wireless-spk\lp-01.tmp\git-template\config: No such file or directory"
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 255

so how could i fix this issue？[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud0rB.png)

i have try to modify Windows Environment variable and add the HOME value, but it does not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOxT7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the config.toml file is incorrect. Please show me its contents.

Alternatively, you can try the following when registering gitlab-runner:

`--executor "shell" --shell "powershell"` -> `-executor "shell" --shell "pwsh"`

This is a process of changing it to PowerShell with administrator privileges.